# In ASP.NET MVC after submitting form. it is not redirecting to other page. its loading same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

1.In  ASP.NET MVC after successfully registration,
 in LogIn when entering fields like username and password and after click on submit button.
2. its not login & not redirecting to another page but it actually looks like refreshing a page and the username entered data is present after clicking submit btn.
my controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using WebApplication6mvc16_12.Models;

namespace WebApplication6mvc16_12.Controllers
{
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddorEdit(int id = 0)//(int id = 0)
        {
            User userModel = new User();
            return View(userModel);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddorEdit(User userModel)
        {
            // using (UserRegistrationDatabase1Entities dbModel = new UserRegistrationDatabase1Entities () )
            using (Database1Entitiesmodel2 db = new Database1Entitiesmodel2())
            {
                //System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type User is not part of the model for the current context.
                //check the AplicationdbContext to be Assign to Var Model that your create
                db.Users.Add(userModel);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.SuccessMessage = "Registration Successful";
            return View("AddorEdit", new User());
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// login data is not getting accepted. on the web server. data access is possible but not redirecting to other page
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>


        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login() //(string UserId)
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(User objUser)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
               // using (Database1Entitiesmodel2 entitiesmodel2 = new Database1Entitiesmodel2())
               using (Database1Entitiesmodel2 db = new Database1Entitiesmodel2())
                {
                    //  var obj = entitiesmodel2.Users.Where(model => model.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && model.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
var var = db.Users.Where(model => model.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && model.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (var != null)
                    {
                        //   Session["UserId"] = var.UserId.ToString();
                        // Session["UserName"] = var.UserName.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("UserDashboard", "UserController");
                    }
                }
            }

            return View(objUser);
        }

        public ActionResult UserDashboard()
        {
           // if (Session["UserId"] != null)
            {
                return View();
           /* }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my login

```
@model WebApplication6mvc16_12.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Login","User",FormMethod.Post))//(Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="form-horizontal">

    @*<select class="form-control" id="LoginAuthority" name="LoginAuthority" required title="here">
            <option disabled selected>Select Role</option>
            <option>Admin</option>
            <option>Customer</option>
            <option>Sevice Engineer</option>
        </select>
    *@
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserId)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-default" />
           @* <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default" />*@
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Registration", "AddorEdit")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

my user

```
namespace WebApplication6mvc16_12.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class User
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required ( ErrorMessage ="This field is required")]
        [DisplayName("Full Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
        [DisplayName("Email Address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required (ErrorMessage =" This field is required")]

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }        

        [Required (ErrorMessage =" This field is required")]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    }
}
```

userdashboard

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserDashboard";
}

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Dashboard Contents
        </legend>

    @*    @if (Session["UserName"] != null)
        {
            < text >
            Welcome @Session["UserName"].ToString()
            </ text >
        }*@
    </fieldset>
<h2>UserDashboard</h2>
```

Comment: Your modelstate is not valid create new class for login model or remove if (ModelState.IsValid) from your actionresult

Answer (score 0):

This behavior seams to be some error in the model validation.

Debug the Post Login action and see if the **ModelState.IsValid** is really valid and if it is showing any error.

**[Update]**

I think the problem is that in your form you are passing only **Username** and **Password**. When it enters the login action, **ModelState.IsValid** will be false because in your model you have **UserId**, **Email** and **Confirm Password**. Try to add this code before **If(ModelState.IsValid)**

```
ModelState.Remove("UserId"); 
ModelState.Remove("Email"); 
ModelState.Remove("ConfirmPassword");
```

Comment: tried that also still it doesn't help.. created another model_class for user_login for username and password.. still it is not working

Comment: Well, if your **ModelState** is ok and your code is reaching the using clause, I can see that you have a problem in *Db* access, or your query is not working to get the user in *DB*

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is moving to "return View(objUser)" due to null. Check once are you getting any data while retrieving "var".

Comment: actually there is no data get for after submission of detail (at which point you are suggesting null )

Comment: at this point "var var = db.Users.Where(model => model.UserName.Equals(objUser.UserName) && model.Password.Equals(objUser.Password)).FirstOrDefault();"

Comment: insert some data to db.Users.

Answer (score 0):

There was a some issue with database and in the model that i had created. i deleted the model and recreated the model with updated database which has an error.